# How to install Brave web browser for 32-bit lubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apt, lubuntu, browser, snap

Trying to install as directed, my Terminal output contains the following:

```
user@user-computer:~$ snap install brave --beta
The program 'snap' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install snapd
user@user-computer:~$ sudo apt install snapd
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ibus-mozc libllvm3.8 libmircommon5 linux-headers-4.4.0-21
  linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-93
  linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-96
  linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  squashfs-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  snapd squashfs-tools
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,625 kB of archives.
After this operation, 41.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/ubuntu xenial/main i386 squashfs-tools i386 1:4.3-3ubuntu2 [111 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 snapd i386 2.28.5 [8,514 kB]
Fetched 8,625 kB in 2s (4,261 kB/s) 
Selecting previously unselected package squashfs-tools.
(Reading database ... 265067 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../squashfs-tools_1%3a4.3-3ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking squashfs-tools (1:4.3-3ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package snapd.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/snapd_2.28.5_i386.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.28.5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up squashfs-tools (1:4.3-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up snapd (2.28.5) ...
user@user-computer:~$ snap install brave --beta
error: snap "brave" not found (at least in channel "beta")
user@user-computer:~$ 
(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:3115): dconf-WARNING **: Unable to open /var/lib/menu-xdg/dconf/profile/user: Permission denied
```

Is the problem that my laptop is 32-bit and this software is 64-bit? Should I change the server to a different country? (How would I do that?)

I suspect the answer is that there is no 32-bit version available, that snap automatically takes into account my processor type, and hence there are no installation files in the 32-bit channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Brave browser snap package has been temporarily discontinued. The current instructions for installing Brave browser in Ubuntu from the official Brave browser website are as follows. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brave-browser
```

#### Update

The brave browser snap package has been resubmitted to the Snap Store and can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo snap install brave
```

The new Brave browser automatically blocks ads and trackers, making it faster and safer than your current browser. This package is official.

Comment: I would say it's implied (since it only lists x64 and 64-bit) but not clearly stated.

Comment: A shame, since the 32 bit machines need it the most.

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the instructions work including [official docs](https://brave.com/linux/) and the reason is that I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 under MacOS Parallels on an M1 (arm64) chip.  I have not yet tried to [build from source](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser), but that will be my next attempt.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt whether using snap is the best way to install Brave on Ubuntu, as I had update problems after following that approach.

I uninstalled the snap version because of the recommendation here on https://snapcraft.io/brave:

> We recommend downloading Brave using the instructions at https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html instead. This Snap is community maintained and may not be on the latest Brave release.

There they recommend:

> ### Release Channel Installation
>
> #### Ubuntu 16.04+ and Mint 18+
>
> ```bsh
> sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
> curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -
> source /etc/os-release
> echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ $UBUNTU_CODENAME main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-${UBUNTU_CODENAME}.list
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install brave-browser
> ```

Answer (score -1):

For Me, after using the brave webpage (https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux) to install the brave browser I needed to run:

root@localhost# sudo apt install brave-browser:amd64

instead of:

root@localhost# sudo apt install brave-browser